# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in my code

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, objective-c-blocks, exc-bad-access

Can be bad access from this part of code?
I'm trying to draw graph.And in my function i have BAD_ACCESS.I can't find what is wrong.
- (void)drawPlot:(SHPlot *)plot {

```
NSDictionary *theme = plot.plotThemeAttributes;

CAShapeLayer *backgroundLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
backgroundLayer.frame = self.bounds;
backgroundLayer.fillColor = ((UIColor *)theme[kPlotFillColorKey]).CGColor;
backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
[backgroundLayer setStrokeColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
[backgroundLayer setLineWidth:((NSNumber *)theme[kPlotStrokeWidthKey]).intValue];

CGMutablePathRef backgroundPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];


UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 75)];
circleLayer.path = circle.CGPath;
circleLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
circleLayer.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
circleLayer.shadowColor =[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
circleLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;

[self.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];

CGMutablePathRef circlePath = CGPathCreateMutable();

CAShapeLayer *graphLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
graphLayer.frame = self.bounds;
graphLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
graphLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
[graphLayer setStrokeColor:((UIColor *)theme[kPlotStrokeColorKey]).CGColor];
[graphLayer setLineWidth:((NSNumber *)theme[kPlotStrokeWidthKey]).intValue];

CGMutablePathRef graphPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

double yRange = [_yAxisRange doubleValue];
double yIntervalValue = yRange / INTERVAL_COUNT;

[plot.plottingValues enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSDictionary *dic = (NSDictionary *)obj;

    [dic enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        int xIndex = [self getIndexForValue:key forPlot:plot];
        double height = self.bounds.size.height - BOTTOM_MARGIN_TO_LEAVE;
        double y = height - ((height / ([_yAxisRange doubleValue] + yIntervalValue)) * [obj doubleValue]);
        (plot.xPoints[xIndex]).x = ceil((plot.xPoints[xIndex]).x);
        (plot.xPoints[xIndex]).y = ceil(y);
    }];
}];

CGPathMoveToPoint(graphPath, NULL, _leftMarginToLeave, plot.xPoints[0].y);
CGPathMoveToPoint(backgroundPath, NULL, _leftMarginToLeave, plot.xPoints[0].y);

int count = _xAxisValues.count;
for(int i=0; i< count; i++){
    CGPoint point = plot.xPoints[i];
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(graphPath, NULL, point.x, point.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(backgroundPath, NULL, point.x, point.y);
    CGPathAddEllipseInRect(circlePath, NULL, CGRectMake(point.x - 5, point.y - 5, 10, 10));
}
CGPathAddLineToPoint(backgroundPath, NULL, _leftMarginToLeave + PLOT_WIDTH, self.bounds.size.height - BOTTOM_MARGIN_TO_LEAVE);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(backgroundPath, NULL, _leftMarginToLeave, self.bounds.size.height - BOTTOM_MARGIN_TO_LEAVE);
CGPathCloseSubpath(backgroundPath);
backgroundLayer.path = backgroundPath;
graphLayer.path = graphPath;
circleLayer.path = circlePath;
CGPathRelease(backgroundPath);
CGPathRelease(circlePath);
CGPathRelease(graphPath);

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
animation.duration = 1;
animation.fromValue = @(0.0);
animation.toValue = @(1.0);
[graphLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];

backgroundLayer.zPosition = 0;
graphLayer.zPosition = 1;
circleLayer.zPosition = 2;

[self.layer addSublayer:graphLayer];
[self.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];
[self.layer addSublayer:backgroundLayer];

NSUInteger count2 = _xAxisValues.count;
for(int i=0; i< count2; i++){
    CGPoint point = plot.xPoints[i];
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    btn.tag = i;
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(point.x - 10, point.y - 10, 40, 40);
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //objc_setAssociatedObject(btn, kAssociatedPlotObject, plot, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

    [self addSubview:btn];
}
circleLayer = nil;
graphLayer = nil;
backgroundLayer = nil;
```

}

This is my full function I have bad access in line         [self addSubview:btn];

Comment: @[user1736025](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1736025/user1736025)  At which line you get this error?

Comment: Who knows…please show the stack trace and any related console messages.

Comment: need some more info for strangers like us to understand the issue. Which line? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I can't find error message.The app is crashed without any log.

Comment: I'm trying to draw graph when I make comment this part of my code everything is ok.After opening this part my app is crashed

Comment: put NSLog(@"some message"); in between and check if the lines are executed or not. Go to the breakpoints on the left side of your xcode and add "All exceptions" to check which line of your code has the issue.

Comment: Then how do you know it was "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"?  If you're seeing that in the debugger, there's usually a list of stacks also…or you can type 'bt' at the debug prompt.

Comment: EXE_BAD_ACCESS should stop at the line where you have a bad access @user1736025

Comment: I add full my function , I have bad access in line         [self addSubview:btn];

Comment: Try [Self.View addSubView:btn];

Answer (score 0):

Move your code into the enumerate block

```
[plot.plottingValues enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSDictionary *dic = (NSDictionary *)obj;

        [dic enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
            int xIndex = [self getIndexForValue:key forPlot:plot];
            double height = self.bounds.size.height - BOTTOM_MARGIN_TO_LEAVE;
            double y = height - ((height / ([_yAxisRange doubleValue] + yIntervalValue)) * [obj doubleValue]);
            (plot.xPoints[xIndex]).x = ceil((plot.xPoints[xIndex]).x);
            (plot.xPoints[xIndex]).y = ceil(y);
        }];
    }];
```